# windows server 2012 4 processors

Tags: windows-server-2012

We have a server with 4 physical processors (individual chips) installed and have installed and activatded Win2012 Standard edition on it..on bare metal i.e. no virtualization.
When I look at the task manager, it only shows two physical processors in the 'Cores' field (# of cores/processor X # of procs seen).

I do understand that ONE Win 2012 Standard license only supports upto 2 physical processors as mentinoed here http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/D/B/4DB352D1-C610-466A-9AAF-EEF4F4CFFF27/WS2012_Licensing-Pricing_FAQ.pdf

What i want to know is- how can I make the same installation (same instance of Win 2012 Std) see, recognize, utilize all 4 processors? Is it even possible? Does it mean adding another license key to the installation? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Comment: why the down vote? This question is about how to apply the license, not about how much it costs et al.

Answer (score 0):

If the standard edition is limited to two physical sockets, to use more you need a higher end license, simple as that. The higher version, I suppose, will be Datacenter edition.

EDIT: looks like there's an option to stack STD licenses:

[image]

No reference on CPU support to be found anywhere, only VM numbers

Comment: Its not as simple as that. The docs say if you have > 2 processors, you 'apply' more licenses to user those additional processors. My confusion is how do we 'apply'?

Comment: please see edit

Comment: That seems strange- I am currently running 3 VMs on a single license.. and it didnt complain even once. But the issue here is not the VM restriction but the physical processor restriction.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do anything.  The licensing requirement is a contractual one, but not a technical one.

If you aren't seeing the processors, check that your BIOS configuration is correct (they are enabled; hyperthreading is enabled, etc.) and that the processors are working.  Consider calling your vendor's support.